# Finding column count with null data in two other columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to find the amount of subjects that only have a baseline weight and not a weight at 6 Months or 12 months. The database provided has roughly 8000 entries and we need to create a query to find this information - they mention it can be achieved through joining - but I continually get results that are tied in with 6 months weight and 12 months weight when I only need that data from baseline weight. For instance, I easily found the data for the amount of people that have baseline weight and 6 months weight

```
SELECT DEMO.ID, DEMO.BL_WGT, [SIX MOS].WEIGHT_6MOS
FROM DEMO RIGHT JOIN [SIX MOS] ON DEMO.ID = [SIX MOS].ID;
```

I can't for the life of my understand how to qualify this data to find only those entries with baseline weight. Any help would be appreciated thank you! Here is the exact question from the assignment.

Part V. Create a new table named WT_LOSS_ALL that has the following fields:

1. ID Number
2. Baseline Weight
3. 6-Month Weight
4. 12-Month Weight

Use the proper join(s) in order to answer the follow questions:

How many participants have only Baseline weight? Baseline & 6 Month Weight? All 3 measures? (5 points)

Comment: Use the *iif()* function inside of a *sum()* aggregate to add either 1 or 0, rather than thinking just in terms of the *count()* aggregate.

Comment: Could you please share DDLs for your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assumption is the default value for the field is null and baseline always have a value

Baseline weight only

```
Select count(id) from WT_LOSS_ALL where 6mos is null and 12mos is null
```

Baseline weight and 6mos

```
Select count(id) from WT_LOSS_ALL where 6mos is not null and 12mos is null
```

All 3
Baseline weight and 6mos

```
Select count(id) from WT_LOSS_ALL where 6mos is not null and 12mos is not null
```